# Differentiate linear transformation

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, linear-transformations, rigid-transformation

Looking at the answer of this question:

[Show that the arc length of a curve is invariant under rigid transformation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448657/show-that-the-arc-length-of-a-curve-is-invariant-under-rigid-transformation)

I don't understand why if $T$ is linear then

$$(T\circ \gamma)'(t)=T\circ \gamma'(t)$$

I will appreciate any comment to help me to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of the chain rule together with the fact that for any linear transformation $T,\ T'(x)=T:$

$(T\circ \gamma)'(t)=T'(\gamma (t))(\gamma'(t))=T(\gamma '(t))=T\circ \gamma'(t).$

Comment: How do you get the third equality?

Comment: $T'(\gamma (t))=T$ since $T$ is linear and $T(\gamma '(t))=T\circ \gamma'(t)$ by def of composition.